# What is the difference between the "command" parameter in the docker-compose.yml and the CMD parameter in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

As you know, in a Dockerfile, you can specify commands through the RUN and CMD parameters (example bellow).

```
...
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pytest
...
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
...
```

In the `docker-compose.yml`, you can also specify the command parameter (example bellow).

```
...

services:
    conteiner_a:
        ...
        command: ["echo", "!!!!!!!! Container_A is available now !!!!!!!!"]
...
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command` parameter in `docker-compose` file is overriding the default `CMD` from the `DockerFile`.

Comment: Replaces or complements?

Comment: Replaces.  A container only ever runs one command.